# SQL top 1 within WITH statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a sql query which makes use of the WITH statement.
The query looks like this:

```
WITH topAge as (
  select top 1 * from ages
  order by age
)

select * from topAge where ageGroup = 1
```

My question is whether the `Where` clause gets executed after the `top` statement, because this query retrieves no records whereas I know that there are records in the database that should be retrieved.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: Yes, the `ageGroup = 1` predicate is only applied after selecting `top 1`. Your query is equivalent to this

```
select * from (
  select top 1 * from ages
  order by age
) where ageGroup = 1
```

What you maybe want is this

```
select top 1 * from ages
where ageGroup = 1
order by age
```

Comment: Thanks, very explanatory example.

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
select top 1 from ages order by age
```

Does not actually select any fields, that's why it's not working, change it to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 age FROM ages ORDER BY age
--           ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, I've editted it to the correct one. I missed it when I was typing it in here :)